# 'type family' vs 'data family', in brief?

Tags: haskell, type-families

I'm confused about how to choose between `data family` and `type family`. The wiki page on [TypeFamilies](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families#Injectivity.2C_type_inference.2C_and_ambiguity) goes into a lot of detail. Occasionally it informally refers to Haskell's `data family` as a "type family" in prose, but of course there is also `type family` in Haskell.

There is a simple example that shows where two versions of code are shown, differing only on whether a `data family` or a `type family` is being declared:

```
-- BAD: f is too ambiguous, due to non-injectivity
-- type family F a
 
-- OK
data family F a 

f :: F a -> F a
f = undefined
 
g :: F Int -> F Int
g x = f x
```

`type` and `data` here have the same meaning, but the `type family` version fails to  type-check, while the `data family` version is fine, because `data family` "creates new types and are therefore injective" (says the wiki page).

My takeaway from all of this is "try `data family` for simple cases, and, if it isn't powerful enough, then try `type family`". Which is fine, but I'd like to understand it better. Is there a Venn diagram or a decision tree I can follow to distinguish when to use which?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't think any decision tree or Venn diagram will exist because the applications for type and data families are pretty wide.

Generally you've already highlighted the key design differences and I would agree with your takeaway to first see if you can get away with `data family`.

For me the key point is that each instance of a `data family` creates a new type, which does substantially limit the power because you can't do what is often the most natural thing and make an existing type be the instance.

For example the `GMapKey` example on the [Haskell wiki page on "indexed types"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Indexed_types) is a reasonably natural fit for data families:

```
class GMapKey k where
  data GMap k :: * -> *
  empty       :: GMap k v
  lookup      :: k -> GMap k v -> Maybe v
  insert      :: k -> v -> GMap k v -> GMap k v
```

The key type of the map `k` is the argument to the data family and the actual map type is the result of the data family (`GMap k`) . As a user of a `GMapKey` instance you're probably quite happy for the `GMap k` type to be abstract to you and just manipulate it via the generic map operations in the type class.

In contrast the `Collects` example on the same wiki page is sort of the opposite:

```
class Collects ce where
  type Elem ce
  empty  :: ce
  insert :: Elem ce -> ce -> ce
  member :: Elem ce -> ce -> Bool
  toList :: ce -> [Elem ce]
```

The argument type is the collection and the result type is the element of the collection. In general a user is going to want to operate on those elements directly using the normal operations on that type. For example the collection might be `IntSet` and the element might be `Int`. Having the `Int` be wrapped up in some other type would be quite inconvenient.

Note -  these two examples are with type classes and therefore don't need the `family` keyword as declaring a type inside a type class implies it must be a family. Exactly the same considerations apply as for standalone families though, it's just a question of how the abstraction is organised.

Comment: > declaring a type inside a type class implies it must be a family."

Thank you, that is a good bit to point out -- that `type`-inside-`class` is basically the same thing as standalone `type family` , just given a shorter name for convenience where `family` is implied.

Comment: Ah.. `data family` creates a new type, as `data F = ...` creates a new type. `type family` does *not* create a new type, as `type F = ...` doesn't create a new type (it just creates an alias). Another sensible parallel :-)

An example: Data.MonoTraversable.Element is a `type family`, so the  right-side of equations are names of existing types; the things are the left side are new synonyms. Since `Element S.ByteString = Word8` and `Element L.ByteString = Word8`, that's non-injective, and a use of `Word8` can't determine which `a` to use in an `Element a`. These definitions are "one-way".

Comment: Whereas in a `data family`, each right-hand side contains a unique constructor (like `XCons` or `XListUnit`), so the definitions are injective  ("reversible") `equations`. So, seeing an `XListUnit` is enough to let the type-inferencer know  we must be working with `XList ()` not an `XList Char`

Comment: Ah, I had a misconception that `type family` was somehow "higher order" than `data family`, in the sense of `kind > type > value`. But in truth, `data` refers to "explicit construction of a type", whereas  `type` refers to `type synonym`. Usually, type synonyms are just abbreviations, but `type family` synonyms have added power: They can make a simple type become a synonym of a "type constructor applied to an argument": `type instance (F A) = B` makes `B` match `F a`. (This is used in `Data.MonoTraversable` to make a simple type `Word8` usable as `Element a`, for `a` = `ByteString`.)

Comment: I disagree with the takeaway to "try a data family first".  Data families are more powerful than type families specifically because they are injective, and are generally much less convenient as well.  I think a better approach is to use a type family unless you specifically require either injectivity or abstraction.

Comment: In my experience injectivity comes up all over the place, so you're saving yourself a lot of future pain if you can use data families. But as you say there's a different set of pain.

Comment: @misterbee - your explanation of the differences is nice and would benefit from being formatted better in an answer. Would it be worth adding your own answer with that content? Otherwise I'd be happy to edit it into mine.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam, I upgraded my comments to an answer, and tagged it Community Wiki. I left out the subjective advice about "when to use which"

Comment: Now that we have injective type families, has your thinking changed?

Answer (score 79):

*(Boosting useful information from comments into an answer.)*

### Standalone vs In-Class declaration

Two syntactically different ways to declare a *type family* and/or *data family*, that are semantically equivalent:

standalone:

> ```
> type family Foo
> data family Bar
> ```

or as part of a typeclass:

```
class C where
   type Foo 
   data Bar
```

both declare a type family, but inside a typeclass the `family` part is implied by the `class` context, so GHC/Haskell abbreviates the declaration.

### "New type" vs "Type Synonym" / "Type Alias"

`data family F` creates a new type, similar to how `data F = ...` creates a new type.

`type family F` does not create a new type, similar to how `type F = Bar Baz`  doesn't create a new type (it just creates an alias/synonym to an existing type).

### Example of non-injectivity of `type family`

An example (slightly modified) from [`Data.MonoTraversable.Element`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.2.0.0/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html):

```
import Data.ByteString as S
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

-- Declare a family of type synonyms, called `Element` 
-- `Element` has kind `* -> *`; it takes one parameter, which we call `container`
type family Element container

-- ByteString is a container for Word8, so...
-- The Element of a `S.ByteString` is a `Word8`
type instance Element S.ByteString = Word8 

-- and the Element of a `L.ByteString` is also `Word8`
type instance Element L.ByteString = Word8
```

In a type family, the right-side of equations `Word8` names an existing type; the things are the left-side creates new synonyms: `Element S.ByteString` and `Element L.ByteString`

Having a synonym means we can interchange  `Element Data.ByteString` with `Word8`:

```
-- `w` is a Word8....
>let w = 0::Word8

-- ... and also an `Element L.ByteString`
>:t w :: Element L.ByteString
w :: Element L.ByteString :: Word8

-- ... and also an `Element S.ByteString`
>:t w :: Element S.ByteString
w :: Element S.ByteString :: Word8

-- but not an `Int`
>:t w :: Int
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Word8'
```

These type synonyms are "non-injective" ("one-way"), and therefore non-invertible.

```
-- As before, `Word8` matches `Element L.ByteString` ...
>(0::Word8)::(Element L.ByteString)

-- .. but  GHC can't infer which `a` is the `Element` of (`L.ByteString` or `S.ByteString` ?):

>(w)::(Element a)
Couldn't match expected type `Element a'
            with actual type `Element a0'
NB: `Element' is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
```

Worse, GHC can't even solve non-ambiguous cases!:

```
type instance Element Int = Bool
> True::(Element a)
> NB: `Element' is a type function, and may not be injective
```

Note the use of "may not be"! I think GHC is being conservative, and refusing to check whether the `Element` truly is injective. (Perhaps because a programmer *could* add another `type instance` later, after importing a pre-compiled module, adding ambiguity.

### Example of injectivity of `data family`

In contrast: In a data family, each right-hand side contains a unique constructor , so the definitions are injective ("reversible") equations.

```
-- Declare a list-like data family
data family XList a

-- Declare a list-like instance for Char
data instance XList Char = XCons Char (XList Char) | XNil

-- Declare a number-like instance for ()
data instance XList () = XListUnit Int

-- ERROR: "Multiple declarations of `XListUnit'"
data instance XList () = XListUnit Bool
-- (Note: GHCI accepts this; the new declaration just replaces the previous one.)
```

With `data family`, seeing the constructor name on the right  (`XCons`, or `XListUnit`)
is enough to let the type-inferencer know we must be working with `XList ()` not an `XList Char`. Since constructor names are unique, these defintions *are* injective/reversible.

### If `type` "just" declares a synonym, why is it semantically useful?

Usually, `type` synonyms are just abbreviations, but `type` family synonyms have added power: They can make a simple type (kind `*`) become a synonym of a "type with kind `* -> *` applied to an argument":

```
type instance F A = B
```

makes `B` match `F a`. This is used, for example, in `Data.MonoTraversable` to make a simple type `Word8` match functions of the type `Element a -> a`  (`Element` is defined above).

For example, (a bit silly), suppose we have a version of `const` that only works with "related" types:

```
> class Const a where constE :: (Element a) -> a -> (Element a)
> instance Const S.ByteString where constE = const

> constE (0::Word8) undefined
ERROR: Couldn't match expected type `Word8' with actual type `Element a0'

-- By providing a match `a = S.ByteString`, `Word8` matches `(Element S.ByteString)`
> constE (0::Word8) (undefined::S.ByteString)  
0

-- impossible, since `Char` cannot match `Element a` under our current definitions.
> constE 'x' undefined
```