# Why is this injective type family not actually injective?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

I tried this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}
module Injective where

type family F (a :: *) = (fa :: *) | fa -> a

convert :: F a ~ F b => a -> b
convert x = x
```

GHC 8.6.4 gave me this error

```
    • Could not deduce: a ~ b
      from the context: F a ~ F b
        bound by the type signature for:
                   convert :: forall a b. (F a ~ F b) => a -> b
        at Injective.hs:6:1-30
```

Why? Surely the whole point of injectivity is that one *can* deduce `a ~ b` from `F a ~ F b`?

Comment: It's probably to do with the difficulties explored here https://repository.brynmawr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1075&context=compsci_pubs. Type Families are kinda total but kinda not. Haskell accepts `F a` even though there's no such instance.

Comment: I completely agree with you, in that the whole point of injectivity _should_ be the deduction you mention! Instead, GHC uses injectivity (roughly) only to accept some types which would have been rejected as ambiguous otherwise (see the GHC docs). I was surprised when I finally understood that injectivity was not being exploited as I expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out this is [a known issue in GHC](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/10833). Apparently it's because it hasn't been proven sound.

Comment: And indeed presuming that type families are total is known to be unsound. (See the Eisenberg+Morris paper.) The code compiles if you supply `type instance Fa = a`, but not if you provide instances less general than that.