# Is anything generative?

Tags: haskell

In the paper ["Higher-order Type-level Programming in Haskell"](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/faculty-of-engineering/computing/public/1718-ug-projects/Csongor-Kiss-Higher-order-type-level-programming-in-Haskell.pdf), an `f :: Type -> Type` is defined to be "generative" in the following way:

> Definition (Generativity). f is generative ⇔ f a ~ g b ⇒ f ~ g

I'm going to explicitly write out the intended quantification as I understand it:

```hs
type IsGenerative :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
class (forall g a b. f a ~ g b => f ~ g) => IsGenerative f
```

Conversely, in words:

> `F :: Type -> Type` is generative if there is no `G :: Type -> Type` besides `F` such that there exist `A, B :: Type` for which `F A ~ G B`

The paper goes on to make a statement about the generativity of unsaturated type-families (they're not generative). To my understanding, in order to be able to form the proposition of whether or not unsaturated type-families are generative, the variables `f, g :: Type -> Type` should range over type-families as well as type constructors. Note that this means the `~` in `f ~ g` must represent some more abstract sense of definitional equality than GHC's `(~) :: (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type) -> Constraint`, which cannot be applied to unsaturated type families.

Now here's the problem: it doesn't seem like anything is generative. You'd expect that a datatype constructor like `Maybe :: Type -> Type` would be generative, but I can easily construct a distinct type family `G :: Type -> Type` and `A, B :: Type` for which `F A ~ G B` (despite `F /~ G`).

```hs
type G :: Type -> Type
type family G a
  where
  G _ = Maybe Int

data Dict c
  where
  Dict :: c => Dict c

lhs :: Dict (Maybe Int ~ G String)
lhs = Dict
```

As I said before, we can't actually form the proposition `Maybe ~ G` within GHC (because `G` is not saturated), but if `F ~ G` is taken to mean "`F` is definitionally equal to `G`", it's pretty obvious that `Maybe /~ G`. So it seems like `Maybe` is not actually generative in the sense defined in the paper. And it seems to me that any `data`/`newtype` is susceptible to a similar sequence of reasoning.

So where am I going wrong?

Is my assumption that `F, G` are allowed to range over type-families as well as type constructors justified? If not, generativity seems like a rather trivial property: "we cannot form the proposition of whether type families are generative, so type families are not generative".

Am I misunderstanding how the variables are quantified in the statement of generativity?

Are there actually any type-level expressions `f :: Type -> Type` that satisfy the formal property of being generative?

Comment: I think the whole point of that section is to state that this doesn't really apply to type families. _The only way the type system can safely assume that `f a ∼ g b` can be decomposed into `f ∼ g` and `a ∼ b` is by ensuring that neither `f` nor `g` can be instantiated with type families. This is achieved by enforcing that type families are always fully saturated, so they can reduce._

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I understand that this is how GHC is implemented, and that's what the paper is trying to explain. But in order to be able to make any sense of the statement "type families, in general, are neither injective, nor generative", you have to be able to form the proposition "is type family X injective/generative" in the first place (so that you can show it is false). If `f`, `g` are precluded from ranging over type families at all, generativity is trivial: for any `f` about which you ask "is `f` generative", the answer is "yes, it is generative". This doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: To put this another way, I read the statement "type families are not generative" as saying: for a type family `F :: Type -> Type`, there may be some `G :: Type -> Type` and `A, B :: Type` such that `F A ~ G B` and yet `F /~ G`. The problem is that this seems to also be true of type constructors.

Comment: Maybe, this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55543598/3195266 (Haskell use injectivity only as a constraint for type inference, not equality).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eh, you're overthinking it. The `~` really is the one from GHC. If you prefer, replace the claim "unsaturated type families are not generative" with "if we expanded `~` to allow unsaturated type families<sup>1</sup>, then they would not be guaranteed generative<sup>2</sup>". This latter fact is (part of) the reason we don't bother expanding `~` to allow unsaturated type families -- it would be much less useful for them than it is for other type expressions.

If they were not precise about this divide in the paper, it's just a bit of slightly sloppy writing, such as we've all done at one point or another.

<sup>1</sup> You can probably deal with the `G`/`Maybe` situation by simply allowing type families on one side of `~` but not the other.

<sup>2</sup> In fact, I believe it's even stronger: they would be guaranteed not to be generative.

Comment: I mean it makes sense, it's just pretty dissatisfying. The entire left hand side of the statement of generativity is just a red-herring in this situation, you can just say `f` is generative if `f ~ g` for some `g`. The reason that's "implied" is because it's true for everything for which you may formulate the proposition of generativity. It still leaves me wanting some formal statement of "parametricity", which is to say the opposite of "case-by-case-y-ness" that characterizes type families.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I think you should conceptualize this slightly differently. Although generativity is given as a property of a type, you should think of it as being a property of a type *system*. We disallow unsaturated type families (and implicitly evaluate saturated ones) so that we get to keep generativity; if we didn't do that, we'd never get to use "`f a ~ g b` => `f ~ g`" during inference, and every damn subterm with a data structure in it would need a type annotation.

Comment: Regarding your bullet points, I agree with 2. For 1, I don't think you can salvage it in any sensible way. If `F` may range over type families but `G` may not, a type family `F` lacking generativity is not really such an interesting statement.

Comment: I've mainly been conceptualizing generativity as a property of _functions_ (in this case they just happen to map types to types). I originally got confused into thinking that generativity is a nice way of distinguishing "parametric" functions, such as `+1`, from "non-parametric" functions, such as `f(0) = 1; f(x) = x`. But it turns out that generative functions don't really exist on any domain besides the trivial one.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin What you call a function mapping types to types, I simply call a type. =) (Compare: a function mapping terms to terms is a term.) So my proposed perspective shift still seems to apply. Or, to say it another way: no function is generative if you allow arbitrary functions, but it may be possible to have a generative function if you restrict the set of functions you consider in your quantifier.

Comment: And what functions should i consider in my quantifier if I am studying this question in a context besides GHC (having no `~` to complain when i put in an "unsaturated type-family")? (not that this has anything to do with the original question)

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin That question is unanswerable as it stands; the answer depends on your unstated goals and desires.

Comment: Well, you just said that your proposed perspective shift "still seems to apply" in the context of functions that map terms of some type to other terms of that type. How? Instead of naively selecting extensional equality as `~`, which would let in "naughty" functions like `f(0) = 1; f(x) = x` and ruin the whole enterprise, what restrictions should i impose on `~` in order for any generative functions to exist?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin `f` isn't naughty if the only other function in existence is `g(x) = 0`. As for what restrictions you should impose on `~`: well, the current ones seem okay to me.

Comment: That would indeed be handy; sadly `g(x) = 0` is not the only other function of type `Int -> Int` to exist. So we need some formula to indicate which functions should be excluded from the domain of `~` in `(exists g x y. f x ~~ g y) => f ~ g`, in order for any functions to be generative. I'm not quite following what you mean by "the current ones seem okay to me", at the moment I'm not restricting the quantifier in any way (which means all functions are allowed, which means nothing is generative).

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin GHC's current rules for `~` seem okay to me. You ask "what restrictions should I put?" and then object when I suggest restrictions like "only `f(0)=1;f(x)=x` and `g(x)=0` exist". So what do you want from me, then?

Comment: GHC's current rules prohibit unsaturated type families and allow type constructors, neither of which have any analog at the term level, so I'm not sure how these rules can be applied in the context of functions `Int -> Int`. I didn't realize the rule you were suggesting was restricting ourselves to only two arbitrarily selected functions: an easier answer in this vein (and roughly equally useful) would be to suggest allowing no functions at all, or only one, all of which are then generative.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Yes, all of that sounds right to me.